# Alternative for the Microsoft Azure C# API

Tags: c#, download, blob

Is there a alternative for the Microsoft Azure C# API. I want to download files from blob urls but a microsoft azure storage **account** is **not** for **free**, so I cannot use it. So is there any other API or way to download blobs?

Example for Blob-Url: [blob:https://flex.aniflex.org/afbf9776-76ea-47dc-9951-2fadafc3adff](http://blob:https://flex.aniflex.org/afbf9776-76ea-47dc-9951-2fadafc3adff)

**Caution**: I'm not the hoster of the file. So I don't want to download the file from my own storage account.

Comment: The api is free of cause. But the storage account which is needed isn't free.

Comment: *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it"* Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@kaskorian I guess you're referring to browsers file blobs...Blob URL/Object URL is a pseudo protocol to allow Blob and File objects to be used as URL source for things like images, download links for binary data and so forth.

Blob URLs can only be generated internally by the browser. URL.createObjectURL() will create a special reference to the Blob or File object which later can be released using URL.revokeObjectURL(). These URLs can only be used locally in the single instance of the browser and in the same session (ie. the life of the page/document).

For example, you can not hand an Image object raw byte-data as it would not know what to do with it. It requires for example images (which are binary data) to be loaded via URLs. This applies to anything that require an URL as source. Instead of uploading the binary data, then serve it back via an URL it is better to use an extra local step to be able to access the data directly without going via a server.